# python - checking if an array consisting of N integers is a permutation

Tags: python

I am analyzing the [routine](https://codesays.com/2014/solution-to-perm-check-by-codility/) which checks if an array of N integers is a permutation (sequence containing each element from 1 to N). 


 I am new to python. I can't grasp how this routine gets the correct answer.  Could anybody explain the logic behind the loop? especially the use of the `counter[element-1]`.


 Is the counter a built-in function working on every element of A? does the `counter[element-1]` reference position/value of elements of A by default because the loop is defined on an array?

```
A=[4,1,3,2]

    def solution(A):
        counter = [0]*len(A)
        limit = len(A)
        for element in A:
            if not 1 <= element <= limit:
                return 0
            else:
                if counter[element-1] != 0:
                    return 0
                else:
                    counter[element-1] = 1

        return 1
```

**Update:**
I modified the code to see the values used within the loop, for example

```
def solution(A):
    counter = [0]*len(A)
    limit = len(A)
    for element in A:
        if not 1 <= element <= limit:
            print element
            print 'outside'
            return 0
        else:
            if counter[element-1] != 0:
                print 'element %d' % element
                print [element-1]
                print counter[element-1]
                return 0
            else:
                counter[element-1] = 1
                print 'element %d' % element
                print [element-1]
                print counter[element-1]

    return 1
```

gives me

```
element 4
[3]
1
element 1
[0]
1
element 3
[2]
1
element 2
[1]
1
1
```

I still don't get the logic. For example fot the first element, why [3] gives 1?

Comment: Try stepping through the code in a debugger.

Comment: Btw the function will choke if there are non-integers in the input.

Comment: Not very error proof solution and not exactly equivalent of the java one, but anw, the counter is a list of `N` elements initialized with 0s. when iterating over array `A`'s elements, since indexing is zero-based, e.g. for element `5` you would check `counter[5-1]` if unset (=0).

Comment: @ flips First element is 4, so that counter[3] correct? what does the counter[3] do? counts occurrences of fourth element of A within A?

Comment: based on your input array `[4,1,3,2]` all iterations will go through the nested `else` because they lie within the limit and are only set once: `counter[4-1]=1`, `counter[1-1]=1`, `counter[3-1]=1`, `counter[2-1]=1`. this `print [element-1]` simply prints a new list with 1 value equal to: `element-1` which is not very helpful. `counter[3]` gets the value of the list at index 3 (4th position) which is originally set to 0 but updated to 1 once a digit is found for the first time.

Comment: _"what does the counter[3] do?"_ - that's array indexing. [RTFM basic syntax](http://hetland.org/writing/instant-python.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind the code is twofold. A permutation of the list [1, 2, ..., N] has two properties. It has only elements between 1 and N and each element just appear one time in the list.
I will try explain it to you part by part this idea in the code.

```
def solution(A):
    counter = [0]*len(A)
    limit = len(A)
```

Assume as an example, a list [1, 3, 2].
`counter` is initialized as a list of zeros of size len(A) = 3. Each 0 correspond to one of the elements of the list

```
for element in A:
        if not 1 <= element <= limit:
            return 0
```

This part condition is the most easy one. If the element is not in this range, the list cannot be a permutation of [1, 2,...N]. For instance, [1, 3, 2] is a permutation of [1, 2, 3] but [1, 6, 2] is not.

```
 else:
            if counter[element-1] != 0:
                return 0
            else:
                counter[element-1] = 1
```

This next part is related with the uniqueness of each term. The `if` checks if a number = element has already passed through this loop. The second `else` make sure that this number is marked, so if a repeated number is found in the next iterations, the `if` will be true and return 0.
For instance, for the list [1, 2, 2]. The first 2 would not trigger the `if`, while the second 2 would trigger it, returning 0. On the other hand, [1, 3, 2], would never trigger the `if`.
If all the number pass this conditions, the two properties were true and the list is a permutation.

Comment: Got it! Excellent explanations!  I am sorry that I am still not able to give points because of my "new-to-the-site" low reputation points.

Comment: I would really like the point because I am also new lol, but do not worry. Pay me back learning something and using it to help the community :).

Answer (score 2):

Quite a cunning algorithm actually.

The input is a sequence of length `N`.

Each element of input is presumed to be an integer (if not, either comparison or indexing will throw an exception).

`counter` is an array of flags - of length `N`, too.

- No integers outside of `[1,N]` range are allowed
- No duplicates are allowed (see how it's done)

Can you now prove that the only way for both conditions to stay true is for the sequence to be a permutation?